# How can I store an array as separate entries in a table?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I recently started learning Django and I've been stuck with this situation for a couple of days now.

From the FE I'm receiving this JSON:

```
{
    "name":"headphones",
    "color" : [
       "green",
       "black"
    ]
}
```

I'm struggling to find a way to store this in the DB. I've got these two tables:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | headphones |

| id | color | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | green | 1 |
| 2 | black | 1 |

I've tried joining tables, and bulky_create but I cannot store the color array from the JSON in the colors table as separate entries. I am using sqlite3 and rest-framework.

Here are the models:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product


class Color(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isAvailable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
```

How can I structure my models to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Share your current model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've edited the answer including the models

Answer (score 0):

if your FE and models are correct you can achieve create operation like this:

```
 class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  color = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length=250), write_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'color']


  def create(self, validated_data):
    colors = validated_data.pop("color")
    product = Product.objects.create(
        **validated_data
    )
    for color in colors:
        Color.objects.create(
            name=color, product_id = product 
        )
    return product
```